# Why is cordova-plugin-file giving me null for cordova.file.dataDirectory?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

Running on an iPhone 6 through Xcode 7.3 and testing in Safari Web Inspector, I am using the Cordova File plugin. I am running example code copied right out of the cordova-plugin-camera docs for saving an image:

```
    function createNewFileEntry(imgUri) {
  console.log("saveImage->createNewFileEntry");

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dirEntry) {
    console.log("createNewFileEntry dir: " + dirEntry);

    // name the file
    var d = getDateTime();
    var fileName = "cc" + d + ".jpeg";

    // JPEG file
    dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
      console.log("createNewFileEntry file: " + fileEntry.fullPath);

      writeFile(dstFileEntry, imgUri);

    }, function() { console.log("Error: createNewFileEntry->getFile"); });

  }, function() { console.log("Error: createNewFileEntry->resolveLocalFileSystemURL"); });
}
```

What happens is that window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()fails because directory spec cordova.file.dataDirectory is null. In fact ALL possible cordova.file.* directories are null. Why?

The following graphic should answer relevant questions- cordova 4.1.1 for iOS is running, cordova File is present, window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL() is valid.

Why are all the symbolic Directory names null?

[image]

[image: This is the config.xml file that is at the root of the app, ./config.xml]

[image: This config.xml is in the ios platform, ./platforms/ios/PayLive/config.xml]

This is the config.xml file that is at the root of the app, ./config.xml
This config.xml is in the ios platform, ./platforms/ios/PayLive/config.xml

Comment: Could you paste you config.xml?

Comment: @utamanna I added them to the original write-up. The first is the config.xml file that is at the root of the app, ./config.xml .  The second is in the ios platform, ./platforms/ios/PayLive/config.xml . 

In the first file it is definitely a surprise to see only two of my 7 plugins: AppVersion, Camera, Compat, NSAppTransportSecurity, File, StatusBar, and BarCodeScanner. But those plugins do appear to be referenced, though in a different way, in the second config.xml, in the iOS Platform folder. What do you make of it?

Comment: The second one is a generated after you run `cordova build ios`. Try adding all the plugins you need using the `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file` command from the command line.

Comment: I have Removed and Added that plugin many times, including just before my post to see if it would magically fix the problem, before I posted. :(

Comment: @utamanna I have to leave right now but when I get back I think I will remove the iOS Platform, the only platform, dummy up the base  ./config.xml (first one above) to contain all the desired plugins, and then re-create/re-add the iOS Platform back. See if that fixes anything.  I'll get back after trying that.

Comment: That sounds good. Also, you are waiting for the deviceready event before trying to save the file from camera right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111254/discussion-between-utamanna-and-ric).

Comment: @utamanna well, you know how frustrating it is when you do non-eventful things and the problem eventually resolves. That's this. I did remove the iOS platform, then manually edited the config.xml, adding all my app's plugins. Then added the iOS Platform back. It didn't work. Then I (again) removed the File plugin from the ios platform using the --save parameter, and then added it back using the --save parameter.  And it worked. Not very satisfying. In fact worrisome because it conveys it may not work again and I have actually learned nothing as to why. I'm moving on but I wanted to get back.

Comment: I'm glad that it started working. I'm sure it would've been a good learning experience for everyone to know what exactly fixed it but at least you get to move on!